# list component as3

Tags: actionscript-3, list, components, dataprovider

My list component for some reason is not displaying the data being pulled from an xml file
Here is the code even though when i do a trace over "question1" Array i get the values.
Could any one be able to tell me what am i doing wrong here?

```
import fl.controls.List;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    var myXML:XML;
    var list:List = new List  ;// new list item
        var question1:Array = new Array();
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("quiz1.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
        function processXML(e:Event):void
        {
         myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
         list.setSize(200,200);
         var xpos = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (list.width / 2);
         var ypos = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (list.height / 2);
         list.move(xpos,ypos);

         for (var i:int=0; i<myXML.*.length(); i++)
         {

          question1.push(myXML.questions[i].@idno);
          trace(question1);

         }
         list.dataProvider=new DataProvider(question1);
         addChildAt(list,0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing an xml property, the return value is typed as XMLList which fl.data.DataProvider doesn't handle when building its internal array.  Give this a try:

```
question1.push(myXML.questions[i].@idno.toString());
```

Another option is to let DataProvider build the data right from the xml but you'll likely need a labelField or labelFunction, try something like this:

```
list.dataProvider=new DataProvider(myXML);
list.labelField = "idno";
```

Also, you may want to access the question node in a item click handler in which case you can build your source array like so:

```
question1.push({
    label:myXML.questions[i].@idno.toString(),
    data:myXML.questions[i]
});
```